# Is this a very bad idea to stop recursion?

Tags: t-sql, recursion, triggers

I have been building some triggers in SQL Server. The purpose of each trigger is to update some data on related records (as they all are). Here is an example of one of the triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.bssProjects_Update
   ON  dbo.Projects
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- workflow to reset the pipelinestatus if the totalCharge changes. remember that there can be many changes at once
UPDATE
    Proj
SET
    Proj.[PipelineStage] = 11
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN Projects Proj on Proj.ID = INS.ID
WHERE
    (INS.[PipelineStage] > 11 and INS.[TotalCharge] != DEL.[TotalCharge])


-- workflow to reset the pipelinestatus if the totalCharge changes. remember that there can be many changes at once
UPDATE
    Proj
SET
    Proj.[PipelineStage] = 13
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN InvoiceLines Invce on Invce.bssToProjectID = INS.ID
    INNER JOIN Projects Proj on Invce.bssToProjectID = Proj.ID
WHERE
    (INS.[PipelineStage] > 11 and INS.[TotalCharge] != DEL.[TotalCharge])


-- workflow to reset the pipelinestatus if the totalCharge changes. remember that there can be many changes at once
UPDATE
    Invce_2
SET
    Invce_2.[InvoiceStatus] = 30
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN InvoiceLines Invce on Invce.bssToProjectID = INS.ID
    INNER JOIN Invoices Invce_2 on Invce.bssToInvoiceID = Invce_2.ID
WHERE
    (INS.[PipelineStage] > 11 and INS.[TotalCharge] != DEL.[TotalCharge])


-- workflow to reset the contributor status if the invoicable value changes. 
UPDATE
    Contrib
SET
    Contrib.[Status] = 40
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Contributors Contrib on Contrib.bssToProjectID = INS.ID
WHERE
    (Contrib.[Status] > 40)
    and (INS.[TranslationCost] != INS.[T1NetInvoiced])


-- on total or cost allocation changes, recalc translator payment.
UPDATE
    Contrib
SET
    Contrib.[Payment] = (INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) * CostAlloc.[TShare],
    Contrib.[ManualPayment] = 0
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN Contributors Contrib on Contrib.bssToProjectID = INS.ID
    INNER JOIN luCostAllocations CostAlloc on INS.CostAllocation = CostAlloc.ID
WHERE
    (Contrib.[ContributorRole] = 2)
    and ((INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) != (DEL.[NetCharge] - DEL.[DiscountCharge]) or INS.[CostAllocation] != DEL.[CostAllocation])


-- on total or cost allocation changes, recalc editor payment.
UPDATE
    Contrib
SET
    Contrib.[Payment] = (INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) * CostAlloc.[EditorShare],
    Contrib.[ManualPayment] = 0
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN Contributors Contrib on Contrib.bssToProjectID = INS.ID
    INNER JOIN luCostAllocations CostAlloc on INS.CostAllocation = CostAlloc.ID
WHERE
    (Contrib.[ContributorRole] = 3)
    and ((INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) != (DEL.[NetCharge] - DEL.[DiscountCharge]) or INS.[CostAllocation] != DEL.[CostAllocation])


-- on total or cost allocation changes, recalc proofreader payment.
UPDATE
    Contrib
SET
    Contrib.[Payment] = (INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) * CostAlloc.[ProofReaderShare],
    Contrib.[ManualPayment] = 0
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN Contributors Contrib on Contrib.bssToProjectID = INS.ID
    INNER JOIN luCostAllocations CostAlloc on INS.CostAllocation = CostAlloc.ID
WHERE
    (Contrib.[ContributorRole] = 4)
    and ((INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) != (DEL.[NetCharge] - DEL.[DiscountCharge]) or INS.[CostAllocation] != DEL.[CostAllocation])


-- on total or cost allocation changes, recalc devexec payment.
UPDATE
    Contrib
SET
    Contrib.[Payment] = (INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) * CostAlloc.[PMShare],
    Contrib.[ManualPayment] = 0
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN Contributors Contrib on Contrib.bssToProjectID = INS.ID
    INNER JOIN luCostAllocations CostAlloc on INS.CostAllocation = CostAlloc.ID
WHERE
    (Contrib.[ContributorRole] = 5)
    and ((INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) != (DEL.[NetCharge] - DEL.[DiscountCharge]) or INS.[CostAllocation] != DEL.[CostAllocation])


-- on total or cost allocation changes, recalc devexec payment.
UPDATE
    Contrib
SET
    Contrib.[Payment] = (INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) * CostAlloc.[DevExecShare],
    Contrib.[ManualPayment] = 0
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN Contributors Contrib on Contrib.bssToProjectID = INS.ID
    INNER JOIN luCostAllocations CostAlloc on INS.CostAllocation = CostAlloc.ID
WHERE
    (Contrib.[ContributorRole] = 6)
    and ((INS.[NetCharge] - INS.[DiscountCharge]) != (DEL.[NetCharge] - DEL.[DiscountCharge]) or INS.[CostAllocation] != DEL.[CostAllocation])

-- clean up any temp tables created in creation process
END
```

Sorry there is so much but I wanted to illustrate that there are lots things going on. I then did a simple change on a projects record - one that did not affect any of the values that are being used in the trigger and I got an error:

Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

On reading about this it means that there are too many recursive actions happening. Each update is causing a call to another trigger - even when nothing is being changed. Indeed, I changed the trigger and replaced all the updates with selects and debugged through it and found that there were no actual updates that were being made. This was all about just travelling through the triggers to look and see.

The trouble is that I want the triggers to function as requested, so I hit upon a strategy of testing the expression first before doing it - only calling the update when there is something to actuially do. Like this:

```
declare @rows as int = 0;
select @rows = count(*)
FROM
    Inserted INS    -- Project record
    INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
    INNER JOIN Projects THIS on THIS.ID = INS.ID
WHERE
    (INS.[PipelineStage] > 11 and INS.[TotalCharge] != DEL.[TotalCharge])

if (@rows > 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        THIS
    SET
        THIS.[PipelineStage] = 11
    FROM
        Inserted INS    -- Project record
        INNER JOIN Deleted DEL ON INS.ID = DEL.ID
        INNER JOIN Projects THIS on THIS.ID = INS.ID
    WHERE
        (INS.[PipelineStage] > 11 and INS.[TotalCharge] != DEL.[TotalCharge])
END
```

It certainly stops the recursion. The question is, Is this a real NONO? I know it will be slower but I'd have thought it would only be marginally slower, even when there was something to do, as the query would already be in place for the actual query.

Your advice would be welcomed
Craig

Comment: Generally speaking, it is considered "bad form" to use triggers to perform application (or DB) logic, like cascading updates or deletes.  Some would even go-so-far as to say triggers are evil.  You might want to read about why people think that.

Comment: I wouldn't say evil but they are tricky and you ahould really know your stuff. Seems to me like you ahould reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of the trigger, check if `@@ROWCOUNT` is zero and if it is do a `RETURN` to exit the trigger. You should perform the check in the first statement (even before `SET NOCOUNT ON`), because any statement might reset `@@ROWCOUNT` and you may get a different result.

Comment: thanks for the comment but it doesn't really address whether putting this amount of logic in a trigger is a good thing or not and the reasons behind it. I think that the thinking is generally that there is a danger of things becoming very complex and difficult to track down so you need to be very careful with triggers. I've also decided that the pre-test section of the code will mostly be faster as it seems likely that there will be nothing to do most of the time.l